# Entity Framework: Not being able to remove child data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Error is throwing when control iterate in foreach loop.

```
foreach (var existingAddress in existingCustomer.Addresses.Where(a => a.AddressID == 5).ToList())
{
    foreach (var CustContacts in existingAddress.Contacts.Where(a => a.ContactID == 5))
    {
        CurrentContacts = CustContacts;
        existingAddress.Contacts.Remove(CurrentContacts);
        //CurrentAddress.Contacts.ToList().ForEach(r => db.Contacts.Remove(CurrentContacts));
    }

    CurrentAddress = existingAddress;
    existingCustomer.Addresses.Remove(CurrentAddress);
    //existingCustomer.Addresses.ToList().ForEach(r => db.Addresses.Remove(CurrentAddress));
}
```

When this line `existingAddress.Contacts.Remove(CurrentContacts);` executes, then error message is

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

If I execute this line `CurrentAddress.Contacts.ToList().ForEach(r => db.Contacts.Remove(CurrentContacts));` instead of this line `existingAddress.Contacts.Remove(CurrentContacts);` then error message i am getting

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am new in EF so I am not being able to figure out how to remove data from child table.

My entity relationship is Customer > Address > Contacts

A customer may have multiple address and each address may have multiple contact details.

My full code as follows which I used to update parent customer object and trying to remove specific data from address and contact child table and also insert two new data in child table.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Addresses CurrentAddress = null;
    Contacts CurrentContacts = null;

    using (var db = new TestDBContext())
    {
        var existingCustomer = db.Customer
        .Include(a => a.Addresses.Select(x => x.Contacts))
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.CustomerID == 5);

        existingCustomer.FirstName = "Test Customer122";

        // selecting address
        foreach (var existingAddress in existingCustomer.Addresses.Where(a => a.AddressID == 5).ToList())
        {
            foreach (var CustContacts in existingAddress.Contacts.Where(a => a.ContactID == 5))
            {
                CurrentContacts = CustContacts;
                existingAddress.Contacts.Remove(CurrentContacts);
                //CurrentAddress.Contacts.ToList().ForEach(r => db.Contacts.Remove(CurrentContacts));
            }

            CurrentAddress = existingAddress;
            existingCustomer.Addresses.Remove(CurrentAddress);
            //existingCustomer.Addresses.ToList().ForEach(r => db.Addresses.Remove(CurrentAddress));
        }


        Addresses oAdrModel = new Addresses();
        oAdrModel.Address1 = "test add2";
        oAdrModel.Address2 = "test add2";
        oAdrModel.SerialNo = 3;
        oAdrModel.IsDefault = true;
        oAdrModel.CustomerID = existingCustomer.CustomerID;
        db.Addresses.Add(oAdrModel);

        Contacts ContactModel = new Contacts();
        ContactModel.Phone = "1111111-33";
        ContactModel.Fax = "1-1111111";
        ContactModel.SerialNo = 4;
        ContactModel.IsDefault = true;
        ContactModel.AddressID = CurrentAddress.AddressID;
        db.Contacts.Add(ContactModel);


        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

### Entity related classes

```
public class CustomerBase
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Fax { get; set; }

}

public class Customer : CustomerBase
{
    public virtual List<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Addresses
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public int SerialNo { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Contacts
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public int SerialNo { get; set; }

    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual Addresses Customer { get; set; } 

}
```

### Full Working code

```
    using (var db = new TestDBContext())
    {
        //db.Database.Log = s => MyLogger.Log("EFApp", s);

        var existingCustomer = db.Customer
        .Include(a => a.Addresses.Select(x => x.Contacts))
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.CustomerID == 5);

        existingCustomer.FirstName = "Test Customer123";

        existingCustomer.Addresses.Where(a => a.AddressID == 5).ToList().ForEach(r => db.Addresses.Remove(r));
        existingCustomer.Addresses.Where(a => a.AddressID == 5).SelectMany(ad => ad.Contacts).Where(c=> c.ContactID==5).ToList().ForEach(r => db.Contacts.Remove(r));

        Addresses oAdrModel = new Addresses();
        oAdrModel.Address1 = "test xxx";
        oAdrModel.Address2 = "test xxx";
        oAdrModel.SerialNo = 3;
        oAdrModel.IsDefault = true;
        oAdrModel.CustomerID = 5;
        db.Addresses.Add(oAdrModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        int CurAddressID = oAdrModel.AddressID;

        Contacts ContactModel = new Contacts();
        ContactModel.Phone = "XX-1111111-33";
        ContactModel.Fax = "XX-1-1111111";
        ContactModel.SerialNo = 4;
        ContactModel.IsDefault = true;
        ContactModel.AddressID = CurAddressID;
        db.Contacts.Add(ContactModel);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't directly related to EF, but to Enumerables.
You can't call `Remove`, `Add` or anything else that modifies the collection on a collection that you are currently enumerating. (Which is why the error message says "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.")

This part for example:

```
foreach (var CustContacts in existingAddress.Contacts.Where(a => a.ContactID == 5))
{
    CurrentContacts = CustContacts;
    existingAddress.Contacts.Remove(CurrentContacts);
}
```

You are enumerating Contacts and within the loop you are removing contacts. A simple workaround is to call `ToList` (as you have done in the outer loop) to make sure you are working with a different Enumeration.

e.g.

```
foreach (var CustContacts in existingAddress.Contacts.Where(a => a.ContactID == 5).ToList())
{
    CurrentContacts = CustContacts;
    existingAddress.Contacts.Remove(CurrentContacts);
}
```

---

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve but from the looks of it you might be better off if you had a clean implementation of **cascade delete** in your database (remove related/connected entries automatically).

Comment: from your code example still it is not clear to me how could i remove address whose address id is 5 and how to remove contact which is associated with address id is 5.

Comment: Probably not, but if you want to delete every single reference by hand it's certainly an option. As I said, a proper cascade delete config of your database would be the smarter way.

Comment: sorry i do not want to do it by cascade delete setup in db level rather i want to delete by code. can u tell me how to do it by code?

Comment: Should be enough to modify the code you already have to prevent the Enumeration from causing the exception as explained above.

Comment: the moment i star working with different collection using tolist() then problem gone. thanks Manfred